# Why does Spark has an option to download pre-built for MapReduce 4.x?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

I'm just getting started with Hadoop. I saw Spark is an execution engine that claims to be faster than MapReduce, hence I want to try it out.

From my understanding, MapReduce is also an execution engine. Then why does Spark has an option to download Spark built for Mapreduce 4.x? I mean I don't get how the 2 fit together in the same stack?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does Spark has an option to download Spark built for Mapreduce 4.x?

It doesn't.  It has the option to download spark built for MapR 4.x.  [MapR is company](http://www.mapr.com/) that develops a distribution of Hadoop.  It is completely unrelated the the mapreduce processing framework of Hadoop.